# jquery: submitting one of several identical forms on website

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I've got several identical forms on my site and submitting one of them causes some strange behvaiour. Here is my setup:

I've got a form on my site with id "#modelform". When #modelform is submitted, a second form appears with class identifier of ".waldform".  #modelform can be submitted several times, allowing several identical .waldforms to exist on my site. Submission of a .waldform calls a python function and appends the returned value to the body of the website.

The problem is as follows: Say I have submitted #modelform twice and there are 2 .waldforms on my site. Submission of the first .waldform to have been created appends its returned value to the body of my site twice. Submission of the second .waldform to will only append its returned value to the body once. Similarly, if there are 3 .waldforms, the first .waldform will append its value 3 times, the second .waldform will append its value twice, and the third will append only once.

I would like each .waldform to append its value only once, regardless of how many exist on the site.

Any thoughts?

Here is my jquery:

```
var $counter = 0

$("#modelform").submit(function() {

    $counter++;

    $('body').append($counter) ;

    //MODEL FORM
    $.post('/estimate', {name: $("#mymodel").val()}, function(data) {

        var $a_var = data['title']
        var $element = $('<div class="item">' + $a_var + '</div><br>');

        $('body').append($element) ;




        //WALD FORM
        $('body').append('<form class="waldform" action="#" method="post"><input type="text" id="waldnum" value="' + $counter + '"/><input type="submit" value="Wald Test" /></form>');

        $(".waldform").submit(function() {

        //post the form values via AJAX...
        $.post('/wald', {name: $(this).find('#waldnum').val()}, function(data) {

            var $a_var = data['title']
            var $element = $('<div class="item">' + $a_var + '</div><br>');

            $('body').append($element);



            });

            return false ;
        });



    });

    return false ;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function you call when the modelform is submitted, you append a form of class waldform, and then attach a submit handler to the ENTIRE class. So, u submit modelform, make a waldform and  give a submit to the first waldform. Then u submit modelform, make a second waldform, and attach a submit event to the whole class, so ur first wald now has 2, the second has 1, and so on and so forth. So, right after appending a new waldform, before you attach the submit event, remove any prior submit handlers with

```
$('.waldform').off();
```

Should fix your problem.

You may want to look into the docs on unbind() and off().

Another way to go about it would be to make a new dom element, bind a submit to it, and then append it to body, instead of binding to the whole class.